# IIS 7.5 receive emails?

Tags: .net, iis, email, iis-7.5

In the good old days with IIS 6, it was possible to use the SEOLib to make a managed hook in the SMTP service that would run whenever a mail got delivered.

In Vista and W7 they stopped shipping SEOLib, so we can no longer develop for it.

What is the replacement for this functionality?

Comment: Still looking for an answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something to do with SMTP Event Sinks ? Take a look : [SMTP event sinks under Windows Server 2008 R2](http://blog.vamsoft.com/2009/12/12/smtp-event-sinks-under-windows-server-2008-r2/).

And maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073289/running-debugging-smtp-event-sinks-under-windows-2008). It seems the SMTP architecture was revised on IIS 7 & Exchange 2007.

Comment: Thanks. That atleast lets it run. I am still wondering how to develop for it, without copying dlls from XP.

Answer (score 1):

Read:

[Custom SMTP in C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4039/custom-smtp-in-c/)
[Send and Receive Mail from C# (SMTP and POP)](http://techisolutions.blogspot.com/2008/03/smtp-and-pop-from-c.html)

Comment: The first link is about creating you own smtp service. I could do that, but I was using IIS to avoid having to make my own service. Easier just to run a VM with IIS6 then. The second link is not receiving mail, it is fetching it.

Comment: @Cine, AFAIK there is no out-the-box service you can subscribe to "Email Received" event. you'll probably have to implement it yourself in this way or another.